# Сохрание значения фильтра

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий фильтр, который выбирается селектором:

```
<select name="filter2" onchange="filtch2(this,'/board/uslugi_v_raznykh_sferakh/142','0','2');">
<option value="0" style="color:#A3A3A3;">Спрос или Предложение</option>
<option value="1">Предлагаю услугу</option>
<option value="2">Ищу услугу</option>
</select>
```

Вопрос такой. При переходе по другим страницам (категориям) можно ли проверять `selected` опций из предыдущей страницы и подставлять их в такой же фильтр. То есть, фильтр при переходе в другие категории сбрасывает значения.

Comment: Можно - `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`

Comment: @Igor правильно ли я понимаю, мне нужен скрипт собирающий в localStorage значение выбранной опции, а затем написать условие при котором будет выбираться опция со значением совпадающим из хранилища?

Comment: Не повлияет ли данный подход на поисковики? По сути, каждый переход в другую категорию будет сопровождаться срабатыванием фильтров и перезагрузкой содержимого страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал вот такую штуковину:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
  var select_val = $("#select option:selected").val();
  localStorage.setItem("test", select_val);
});

$("#select option").filter(function() {
  return ($(this).val() == localStorage.getItem("test"));
}).prop('selected', true);

$('#select').change(); // Это нужно, если к опциям привязана какая-то фукнция
```

Пояснять особо нечего, выбранную опцию при клике сохраняем в кеш. Затем в этом же селекторе находим совпадение значения и применяем `selected` к этому пункту.